# Is there a way to add more settings?

Tags: settings

I want to do some things like disable system sounds and change some animations. I'm new to linux though, and this OS. Is it possible on elementary or is there an application i can install for more settings? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can disable system sound from the sound menu in the settings
You can also install elementary tweaks to add more settings, if it's what you mean

These are the commands to be typed or copied/pasted in your terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
```